# Helm Nginx Ingress: How to turn off server-tokens?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

There's [a setting](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#server-tokens) to turn off the NGINX Server header, but I'm new to Kubernetes and Helm so I don't actually know how to set it.

I've tried to turn off server tokens like so:

```
helm upgrade --reuse-values nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress -ndefault --set controller.config.server-tokens='"false"'
```

Which is indeed reflected when I read back the chart values:

```
❯ helm get values nginx-ingress -ndefault

USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
controller:
  config:
    server-tokens: '"false"'
  publishService:
    enabled: true
```

And in the YAML:

```
❯ kubectl get -n default configmap  ingress-controller-leader-nginx -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  server-tokens: "false"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  ...
```

But it doesn't seem to be applied against the internal `nginx.conf`:

```
❯ kubectl exec -ndefault nginx-ingress-controller-b545558d8-829dz -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep tokens
        server_tokens on;
```

And also my web-server is still sending the `server:` header.

Do I have to reboot the service for the ConfigMap to be reflected or what? How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

<del>I think it has to be a capital F in `False`.</del> Doesn't need to be. It just wasn't taking before. I don't know why. [This](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/226#issuecomment-391183286) and [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/226#issuecomment-391210099) both work.

```
❯ kubectl get configmap -ndefault nginx-ingress-controller -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  server-tokens: "False"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nginx-ingress
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2020-06-19T06:37:21Z"
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.37.0
    component: controller
    heritage: Helm
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "7130237"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/nginx-ingress-controller
  uid: 633efe3a-73cf-4c40-8e40-581937e367e2
```

You can do this manually by editing the configmap via `kubectl edit configmap` and then deleting the controller pod, or you can set it via helm values:

```
helm get values nginx-ingress -ndefault -oyaml > tmp/nginx-ingress-values.yaml
```

Change to:

```
controller:
  config:
    server-tokens: "False"
  publishService:
    enabled: true
```

And apply it:

```
helm upgrade nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress -f tmp/nginx-ingress-values.yaml -ndefault
```

Delete the controller pod for good measure.

Grep it:

```
kubectl exec -ndefault nginx-ingress-controller-b545558d8-gmz64  -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep tokens
```

Confirm your headers in Chrome dev tools:

[image]

---

Perhaps more simply this would have worked:

```
helm upgrade --reuse-values nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress -ndefault --set-string controller.config.server-tokens=false
```

But my config is working now so I'm not going to try it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/#nginx-configuration) of nginx ingress controller

> The goal of this Ingress controller is the assembly of a configuration file (nginx.conf).The main implication of this requirement is the need to reload NGINX
>   after any change in the configuration file

So you have two options

1. Since nginx pods are deployed using a `deployment` you can just delete the pods and kubernetes will recreate the pods with updated configuration.
2. From helm 3 docs [here](https://v3.helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments)

Often times ConfigMaps or Secrets are injected as configuration files in containers or there are other external dependency changes that require rolling pods. Depending on the application a restart may be required should those be updated with a subsequent helm upgrade, but if the deployment spec itself didn't change the application keeps running with the old configuration resulting in an inconsistent deployment.

The `sha256sum` function can be used to ensure a deployment's annotation section is updated if another file changes:

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
[...]
```

Comment: Hmm, it appears `--recreate-pods` is deprecated, but it still works. The pods did restart, but the setting still isn't taking.

Comment: nginx conf inside the pod is not updated ? Helm 3 the way to rollout ConfigMap changes is different and yes --recreate-pods is deprecated and I remove it from the answer

Comment: Correct, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is not being updated. I tried manually deleting the pod too, but it still isn't there in the new pod.